# Why Do Our React Query Refetches Cause 401 Responses?

Tags: jwt, keycloak, react-query

we have an app that uses keycloak to issue and validate JWTs.

we also use react-query and we have set `refetchOnWindowFocus` to true.

when react-query refetches the data after some time of inactivity, without the user interacting with the window, we get 401 responses from our server. as soon as we interact with the page, the same request returns a successful 200 response. the network tab looks like this:

[image: network tab]

as soon as i focus the window after some time of inactivity, i get the refetch along with 3 retries (as configured) and they result in 401 responses. as soon as i actively click inside the browser window, the request fires again and i get a 200 response.

why is that?

<s>it seems that the requests are the same in both situations, as far as i can tell from the network tab. the Bearer token in the `Authorization` header is the same.</s> <- this turns out to be incorrect. the tokens used are different. the requests that resulted in a 401 used outdated tokens. see my answer below for details.

what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix the issue. As it turns out the `useKeycloak` hook from `react-keycloak/web` does not handle the token state reactively (https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak/issues/116).

This caused our `useAuthenticationHelper` to use outdated tokens.

The workaround that does the trick for us (at least for the short term) is to use the `onTokens` event listener of the `ReactKeycloakProvider` to update a globally available TokenContext and consume that context in our `useAuthenticationHelper`.

Since the `react-keycloak` library is no longer maintained, we will migrate to `react-oidc-context` soon.